# PL/SQL With Object Types PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have create object relation type as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE familycar_t AS OBJECT (
make VARCHAR (10),
model VARCHAR(10),
year NUMBER (4),
fuel_type VARCHAR (10));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sedan_t AS OBJECT (
familycar ref familycar_t,
cylinder_Size  number(10));
/

CREATE TABLE familycar OF familycar_t (PRIMARY KEY (make,model));
```

Now I want to set primary for "Sedan" table as follow.

```
CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (familycar_t.make,familycar_t.model));
```

But Error occur like,

> Error starting at line : 4 in command - CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t
>   (PRIMARY KEY (familycar_t.make,familycar_t.model)) Error report - SQL
>   Error: ORA-00904: "FAMILYCAR_T"."MAKE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

What is the solution for it?

Comment: Have you tried:  `PRIMARY KEY (familycar.make, familycar.model)`?  That is, reference the object, not the type.

Comment: I have try below ways, but not correct... CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (make%familycar,model%familycar));

CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (familycar.make%familycar_t,familycar.model%familycar_t));

CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (familycar.make%familycar_t,familycar.model%familycar_t));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using references is to use inheritance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE familycar_t AS OBJECT (
  make VARCHAR (10),
  model VARCHAR(10),
  year NUMBER (4),
  fuel_type VARCHAR (10)
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sedan_t UNDER familycar_t (
  cylinder_Size  number(10)
);
/

CREATE TABLE familycar OF familycar_t (PRIMARY KEY (make,model));

CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (make,model));
```

However, you don't really need the `sedan` table in this case:

```
INSERT INTO familycar
SELECT sedan_t( 'Ford', 'Model-T', 1908, 'Petrol', 4 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT familycar_t( 'Ford', 'Model-A', 1903, 'Petrol' ) FROM DUAL;

SELECT f.*,
       TREAT( VALUE(f) AS sedan_t ).cylinder_size AS cylinder_size
FROM   familycar f;
```

**Output**:

```
MAKE       MODEL            YEAR FUEL_TYPE  CYLINDER_SIZE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
Ford       Model-T          1908 Petrol                 4 
Ford       Model-A          1903 Petrol            (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an index on attributes whose type is REF (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5013.htm#SQLRF01209)).
You can only define indexes on REF attributes or columns if the REF is scoped.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sedan_t AS OBJECT (
    familycar familycar_t,
    cylinder_Size  number(10)
    );
/
CREATE TABLE sedan OF sedan_t (PRIMARY KEY (familycar.make, familycar.model));

Table SEDAN created.
```